# How to center the second inline-block element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want my first element to be on the left and my second element to be in the exact center of the screen (while being horizontally aligned). Logo/text left, navigation bar in the middle.

I cant seem to get the following result with the code below:

|red|-------|green|------------|

**I want the center of the Green square in the middle of the screen**. Which would normally happen if I used text-align: center; on a single element if its not inline-blocked.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="red-color"></div>
    <div class="green-color"></div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
.red-color {
        background-color: red;
        padding: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .green-color {
        background-color: green;
        padding: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

Would really appreciate any advice, I have been stuck on this for a few days now already. I've tried to wrap them both up in a div and text-align: center; them. but then I cant seem to push the red square back to the left.

And while I can do it by playing with the margins and eyeballing the center, this does not feel like the optimal solution.

Comment: hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .main{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        
    }
    .red-color {
        background-color: red;
        width: 30%;
      }

      .green-color {
        background-color: green;
        width: 30%;
      }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="red-color">logo/text</div>
        <div class="green-color">navbar</div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

> u can use `flexbox` to adjust elements accordingly. I created a main-div then gave height and width and then its has green and red div's , I applied flex property to main and gave width to each div so , by adjusting the width u can change the position of logo or navbar.

Comment: hmm I have a short follow up question:

my navbar has 5 options: Home - About - Gallery - FAQ - Contact

I want Gallery to be in the exact middle of the screen (because its the middle of the navbar). Is there no option to say: The middle of the navbar should go in the middle of the screen? 

Now every time I change the font-size / font / font weight/etc. I have to restructure everything.

Comment: you can give width to all navbar elements like 20% for 5 elemnts and the gallery will always in the middle but u do have to rewrite code for small screen as 20% of the width is very small compare to big screens

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`enter code here`
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .main{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        
    }
    .red-color {
        background-color: red;
        width: 30%;
        margin-right: 5%;
      }

      .green-color {
        background-color: green;
        width: 30%;
       margin-left: 10%;
      }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="red-color">logo/text</div>
        <div class="green-color">navbar</div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, but now I need the middle of the green nav bar in the middle of the screen. (with your code the left side of the nav bar is in the middle)

Because I have 5 options in the navbar horizontally centered, A B C D E and I want option C to always be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Hi, you mean you want the "text" inside the Green box to be at the center or the whole green bar to be at the center of the screen? pls explain

Comment: Hmm, Let me rephrase it a bit, 

If the green box is 100px, I want it to be in the exact middle, meaning that it has 50px to the left of the center and 50px to the right of the center.